# Django static files problem

Tags: python, django

### Duplicate of [Django staticfiles app help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565935/django-staticfiles-app-help)

I'm using Django 1.3 beta and the static files app is confusing. In development mode it is meant to automatically serve files from the `STATIC_URL` path.

> From http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/
>
> If you're using the built-in
>   development server (the runserver
>   management command) and have the DEBUG
>   setting set to True, your staticfiles
>   will automatically be served from
>   STATIC_URL in development.

This didn't seem to work, so I tried a url pattern ('/static/') which routes to the static.serve view. This just 404'd. Somehow it conflicts with the STATIC_URL, if I change it to 'assets/' it will serve the files from static just fine. It's only logical to use '/static' for the static url, but this conflicts.

Url Patterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Serve static files for *development only*
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

Static files settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/dave/static/flux'

# URL that handles the static files served from STATIC_ROOT.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Ideally I would like Django to use the static url for seving files in development without having to use any urlpatterns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [django staticfiles app help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565935/django-staticfiles-app-help)

Comment: Go ahead and vote to close/delete your own question then.

Comment: I don't have the reputation required to do that. I've voted to close but it needs more votes. I think I've made it clear enough that it's a duplicate to avoid wasting peoples time as much as I can.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to serve up the static files while using the built in Django server you will need to add a urlpattern.  This is what I do (add this after all your other patterns:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
            (r'^static/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_PATH}),
    )
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'build in django server"??