# How to make Django find a static css file

Tags: django, static

I am going nuts with muy current Django project and its static files. I tried different solutions on SO 
 (e.g. [Django cannot find my static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089055/django-cannot-find-my-static-files) and [Django Static Files CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848102/django-static-files-css)) and even my very own working ones from my other projects..

I just want to link a basic css file located in my projects /static/ folder to my base.html file which will contain the basic navbar for all sites/apps within the project. That's why I decided to place it in the projects directory centrally. Somehow it won't find the file though.

This is my setup where

- debug is set to *True* (development, no production yet)

**settings.py:**

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join('static'), )
```

**base.html:**

```
{% load static %}
[...]
            {% block head_css_site %}
              <link href="{% static 'base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            {% endblock head_css_site %}
[...]
```

**project structure:**

[image]

**error:**

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/base.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your templates. As you can see, the request that is being made does not include the static prefix, which indicates that `STATIC_URL` is not defined. And, in fact, the `{% load static %}` you give at the top of the template does not (and cannot) define that variable. What it *does* do is give you access to the `static` template tag, which you use like this:

```
<link href="{% static 'base.css' %}"...>
```

**Edit**

Additionally, your static folder appears to be within your "dashex" directory, rather than the base dir. So you should either move it, or change the setting:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join('dashex/static'), )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr. Roseman. I adapted  your solution and the requested URL looks fine now. However, it still won't find the file? New error: `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashex/static/base.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`. But going from the main dashex project folder it should be correct with `/dashex/static/base.css` where the manage.py file runs the development server.

Comment: No, with the code you've given, the URL using this tag would be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/base.css`. Where did `dashex` come from?

Comment: ah i tried to implement another solution given below and changed the static_url to `dashex/static/`. Changed it back again and I end up with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/base.css` now, but still `error not found`. Now I am totally confused. Why do both urls `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/base.css` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashex/static/base.css` end up with `ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` ?

Comment: I moved the `templates` and `static` folders to the very main directory. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this :

```
    python manage.py collectstatic
```

in the project, root to force it to collect static files

or set debug=True 
or run :

```
./manate.py runserver --insecure
```

Comment: I am not in production yet, so this isn't the key here I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You must try giving the path to static files in the `urls.py` like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

check out the docs here [Serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

Comment: Added it, but still the same error. The GET is the issue I guess, not sure how to solve it though.