# jpg and css files are missing

Tags: django

I'm new to django. so I need your help. I am having a problem, my css and jpgs 
are missing. I read this tutorial [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/). But found no luck. Can any one help me?? thanks

setting.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/khalsa/projects/template2/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

URL setting

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
    }),
 )
```

Image Path

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/11.jpg" alt="image" />
```

Comment: Please define "are missing." Are you unable to access them by URL (which URL?) or have they vanished from your hard drive?

Comment: @George Cummins I'm trying to display images. which is located in `static/images/` folder. Generic view  `(r'^test/$', list_detail.object_list, product_info),`

Comment: What version of Django are you using, and are you using `manage.py runserver` or a real web server?

Comment: @George Cummins Django version is 1.3.0 Final. and I'm using it localhost. yes ` manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to check.

1. Did you run `./manage.py collectstatic`? Did the process successfully copy your files to  'C:/Users/khalsa/projects/template2/static'?
2. Localhost issues: Is Django is using 'http://127.0.0.1/static/' and you are using 'http://localhost/static/' in your browser, or vice-versa?
3. Finally, you will need to determine if `runserver` serves the static files. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/) says "Deploy those files by configuring your webserver of choice to serve the files in STATIC_ROOT at STATIC_URL." I am not sure `manage.py runserver` does this by default.

Comment: thanks for reply. 1 All files successfully copied. using `manage.py collectstatic`. 2. Django is using `http://127.0.0.1` but `http://127.0.0.1/static `is not working.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565935/django-staticfiles-app-help, Django docs recommend that you do not place your files in STATIC_ROOT. Instead, they should be placed elsewhere and then be collected by `collectstatic`. Did you save them elsewhere? As a workaround, you can add (or edit) this setting: `STATICFILES_DIRS = (STATIC_ROOT,)`

Comment: what does this mean? `Django docs recommend that you do not place your files in STATIC_ROOT`

Comment: @user559744: the idea behind `collectstatic` is that your static files are stored in various places, and the command will find all of those places and copy the files into STATIC_ROOT. If your files are already in STATIC_ROOT, perhaps `collectstatic` just ignores them, so they never get recognized.