# Serving static file with django

Tags: django

I am new to Django and am trying to learn how to serve static files in local deployment. I have read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) and many other possible related problems from stackoverflow but i cant seem to be able to find solve my problem.

This is my settings , I cant figure out what is the reason Django isnt serving my static files

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/html/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=('C:/Users/RayLim/Desktop/project/home/username/djcode/mysite/mysite/templates/html',)
```

In my templates I refer to them as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

The structure of my html file which is located at `C:/Users/RayLim/Desktop/project/home/username/djcode/mysite/mysite/templates`

```
html
 /css
  /images
  /style.css
 /js
  /jquery.jcarousel.pack
  /jquery-1.4.1.min
  /jquery-func
```

This is the server response

```
"GET /home/css/images/big1.jpg HTTP 1.1" 404 3782
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, static files and templates are usually in separate directories but I don't think there would be any problem (that I'm aware of...)

Next, you want to make sure that you use a template tag to represent the static file location instead of using `css/..` which expects there to be a `css` directory relative to whatever url you are currently viewing.

There are [a couple template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) you can use, I use [`{{ STATIC_URL }}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs)

So replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

And you should be all set...

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid hard linking to your static directories. It can cause confusion and potential problems as your project gets bigger

Please refer to this, it has everything you need.

[Django staticfiles app help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565935/django-staticfiles-app-help)

Comment: @stupidboo correct , i tried reading the link but i didnt quite get how to do it , i learn better by following examples. Do you have any examples to follow???