# django admin css on apache server

Tags: css, django, apache2

I need to solve the missing admin page css problem. I have tested almost all the solutions on the web with no luck! (I'm using django 1.8 on apache2.4)

Here's what I've done so far:

in `setting.py` I have:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
```

I did `python manage.py collectstatic`. It created the static folder: 63 static files copied to '/var/www/mysite/mysite/static'.

and then in `etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` I added:

```
Alias /static /var/www/mysite/mysit/static
<Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I also reloaded the apache.

It seems that I'm doing something wrong since the django admin doesn't show the css.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you done `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django staticfiles app help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565935/django-staticfiles-app-help)

Comment: does your static files work correctly not in admin?

Comment: @dahrens yes, I did the `python manage.py collectstatic` and it successfully created the folder: 63 static files copied to '/var/www/mysite/mysite/static'.

The [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565935/django-staticfiles-app-help](Django staticfiles app help) is old and for django 1.3

Comment: @ZagorodniyOlexiy No it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The steps presented in the question is actually correct to set the static files on apache server."

The problem was the typo I made in my apache server thread (the correct one is: `Alias /static /var/www/mysite/mysite/static`). Thanks to @Zagorodniy Olexiy for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

After all you wrote I think that the problem is right of the files and directories of your project. Try customize it in this way:

1) Change the rights of all files in your project:

```
chmod 755 /var/www/mysite/*
```

2) Change rights to the folders of your project:

```
find /var/www/mysite/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

3) Change owner of your project:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mysite/*
```

Also you have typo in your apache server thread:

remove

```
Alias /static /var/www/mysite/mysit/static
```

to

```
Alias /static /var/www/mysite/mysite/static
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The problem was the "typo"! Thank you very much for pointing it out.